# MS Access - How do I make a button on a form that simply counts?

Tags: forms, count, ms-access-2010

I need to make a tool that simply records how many times a button was pressed for a given label. There will be 10 of these label + button pairs. The labels will be the names of people. Each time the button is pressed, the a value of 1 is added to that person. Ideally, I'd like this to be recorded in a table. I am attempting to do this with a macro and am currently testing with the On Click - GoToControl. Does anyone know if this is the right way to do this or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the table has one record in it?  If so, in the OnClick event of the button just run an Update statement on the data.  Something like this (aircode):

```
Dim str as String
str = "Update MyTable Set MyField = MyField + 1"
DoCmd.RunSQL str
```